# INSTAGRAM API - Get username from account id

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am using Instagram webhooks to be notified when a user mentions my account. In this webhook, I have a *sender id* and a *recipient id*.
These are the *instagram account ids* of the account that did the mention and the account that has been mentioned.
What I would like to do is to be able to replace these ids with the username of the account.
Since the username of an account is public, I guess there is a way to achieve this but I didn't find how.

Thanks for your help !